# pkg: /data/local/tmp.... Failure [INSTALL_CANCELED_BY_USER]

Tags: android

I'm using Android Studio to connect to run app in my **Xiaomi Redmi Note 3G** device .

My device is already found in the Choose Device Dialog, but I keep getting an error :

```
Target device: xiomi-hm_note_1w-MZI78PZDHESSRWMN
Uploading file
   local path: C:\Users\fadzlan\AndroidStudioProjects\HybridSecurity\app\buj
   remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.fyp.fadzlan.hybridsecurity
Installing com.fyp.fadzlan.hybridsecurity
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.fyp.fadzlan.hybridsecurty"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.fyp.fadzlan.hybridsecurity
Failure [INSTALL_CANCELED_BY_USER]
```

Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: Restart `ADB` or try plugging your device off then on

Comment: like i said, i keep getting an error.
so i already did so many time even restart @hrskrs

Comment: @kuciyang did u solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me as well.
I figured out that the phone needs to be in active mode ( not sleep) when you run the app.